# cannot run a app in studio android. SelectDeploymentTarget

Tags: java, android, sdk

i have a problem in my Studio android program which is:
     i can't run my app when my select deployment target window show up, 
     and just that message show up:

```
 "missing feature (WATCH)", and the pgm prepose to me those tow things:

*No USB devices or running emulators detected.
*VT-x is desabled in BIOS.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfdeY.jpg][1]


 [https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4mnB.jpg][2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run an Android app, Android Studio needs either a real physical android device or a virtual machine to run the code on.  Those are referred to as Deployment Targets.  Those messages mean that you do not have a physical Android device plugged in (or the drivers are not set up so that a device is recognized, or some other such reason), and that your computer's CPU doesn't have virtualization turned on in order for you to have a virtual Android device.  You can change this in your BIOS settings if your CPU does have virtulization, and then you'd have to create a virtual device using the virtual device manager that comes with the SDK.

Note: I am not sure if the virtualization NEEDS to be turned on for a virtual device or if it just ENHANCES a virtual device's performance.  In any case, you don't have a virtual device and the virtualization capabilities of your processor are not turned on.